# Google Vision API: both English and Arabic on the image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

We are trying to read Text from images that have both English and / or Arabic text in them. We do need to extract both languages' detected text.
When passing the hints as en and ar, sometimes the English are being mis-interpreted for Arabic text. Although if we pass English alone as a preferred language to the vision service call, the english text is returned correctly.
But since we need both, I suppose we have to pass both en and ar.
Is this correct? Is there anything we can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

As per [OCR Languages Support](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages) documentation, it seems English language doesn't have to be specified as it is Latin alphabet. Did you try to specify only Arabic in hints?

If that doesn't work, could you share an example of image as attachment to this post, and the code showing how you issue the API call? Also you can post the meaningful part of the response.